# Need help configuring SQL Server CE connections string in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to return a session factory using this code:

```
return Fluently.Configure()
.Database(MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard.ShowSql().ConnectionString(path))
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Project>())
.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Path is the full path to an .sdf file.

And get this exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.ConStringUtil.GetKeyValuePair(Char[] connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, String& key, Char[] valuebuf, Int32& vallength, Boolean& isempty)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
return Fluently.Configure()
                        .Database(MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard.ShowSql().ConnectionString(c => c.Is("data source=" + path)))
                        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Project>())
                        .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Source here:
http://marekblotny.blogspot.com/2009/02/fluentconfiguration-new-api-to.html

Answer (score 0):

http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce

I've never used an sdf before, but my guess is to try something like this.  You have to use a valid connection string, and simply providing the path is not a valid connection string.

```
Data Source=C:\mydatabase.sdf;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Pass that in instead of path. Ideally this would come from the connection strings section in your config file.

Comment: try `.FromConnectionStringWithKey` and put your connection string with the path in it in your config file.

Comment: I can't do that because the app needs to be able to switch between different sdf files. It must be done through code.

Comment: You can have more than one connection string in the config and then just change which connection name you are passing into `.FromConnectionStringWithKey`

Comment: The files are not known in advance. They're like word or excel files. The application is supposed to open any file.

Comment: Ah, well then you could just use `String.Format("Data Source={0};", path);` and inject the path into the connection string.